Estimate probability value is greater than x from an unknown distribution
Lets say that we have a population of N items that has a value from 0 to 6000.
Let's say that the mean of the population is $\mu$.
We do not know the distribution of the items.
We extract a item from this population, How can we estimate $P(x\geq 2500)$?
Same problem, assuming that the distribution is uniform.
Edited:
We only have the following information about $P(x>y)$:

The population has $N=100$ items
$x \in [0, 6000]; x \in \Re$
$\mu = 1200$
We want to use the quadratic loss funtion for our estimation

We lack the following information (but we can make an assumption, if so please spedify it):

The real distribution of x
The standard deviation (std) of x


I think you might need to specify the question. Is the distribution of the $x$ uniform as you said in the last sentence or is it some unknown distribution? Also, are the $x$ integers or reals?

If the distribution is uniform from $0$ through to $6000$ then $\mu=3000$.  Clearly $P(X \ge 2500)$ would then be $\frac{3500}{6000}$ with a continuous uniform distribution or $\frac{3501}{6001}$ for a discrete uniform distribution on the integers.

x is real.
0 and 6000 are de maximun posible values, but we do not know if there is any value of 6000 or 0. So we only know N, $\mu$ and x \in [0, 6000] from the distribution

You describe a Bernoulli experiment where you observe whether $x$ exceeds $2500$ or not and you wish to estimate its parameter $p.$  This is standard textbook fare.  The better books explain how the solution depends on your loss function: there is no unique solution.  So, to help us understand what kind of answer you are looking for, please give us some information about your application and your analytical objectives.

The sample proportion $\geq$ 2500 is a common choice with some convenient properties but as whuber points out, choice of estimator depends on your loss function  (/what you want to optimize).

Synopsis
Based on a single observation you can make a defensible estimate of this probability, one that is better than outright guessing.  But there are many possible estimates.  They depend on two things: what it costs you to guess wrong and what your expectations are concerning the likely answers.  In any real statistical application you should be able to stipulate the costs, at least approximately; so choosing a good estimator comes down to evaluating how well it performs across the whole range of possible answers.  That is done (conceptually, at least) by comparing risk curves.

More Detailed Answer
The solution depends on your loss function.  This tells you the relative cost of incorrectly estimating the probability $p = \Pr(X\ge 2500),$ where $X$ is a random variable modeling the observation $x.$  The loss depends on your estimate and on the true value and should be smaller for estimates close to the true value.
Even then, there often is no one obvious best solution.  This becomes clear by plotting the risk functions.  The risk of an estimator $t$ (which assigns a guess of $p$ to an observation $x$) is the expected loss of $t(X).$  It depends on the one thing you don't know: $p.$  Some risk functions will be better for some values of $p$ and worse for other values.
Let me illustrate, leaving the definitions and math to the textbooks and threads discussing these concepts.  The math in this one-observation case is delightfully simple, making it good for learning: an estimator $t$ only needs to guess two possible values of $p:$ one when $x \geq 2500$ is observed, which I will call $t(1),$ and one when $x< 2500$ is observed, which I will call $t(0)$.  Writing $\mathcal L$ for the loss, the risk of an estimator $t$ is
$$r_{\mathcal L, t}(p) = p \mathcal L(t(1), p) + (1-p) \mathcal L(t(0), p).$$
A common loss function is quadratic loss:
$$\mathcal L(t, p) = (t - p)^2.$$
For comparison I will illustrate a relative loss:
$$\mathcal L(t, p) = \frac{|t - p|}{2(t+p)},$$
assuming we aren't making stupid negative guesses (where $t+p$ might be negative).
To show you a variety of estimators I have chosen the following:

$(1/4, 3/4) = (t(0), t(1))$ guesses $p=3/4$ when $x\ge 2500$ and otherwise guesses $p=1/4.$  As you will see below, this has a special property for quadratic loss.

Bayes$(1,3)$ is the estimator with smallest posterior expected loss when the prior distribution of $p$ is Beta$(1,3).$  This distribution focuses much of its probability near $p=1/4.$  It is the estimator with $(t(0),t(1)) = (1/5, 2/5).$

Constant always guesses $p=1/2$ no matter what $x$ might be.

Identity guesses what was observed (it's the Maximum Likelihood and Method of Moments estimator), corresponding to $(t(0),t(1)) = (0,1).$

Inverted is an intentionally bad estimator that guesses $p=2/3$ when $x\lt 2500$ and $p=1/3$ when $x \ge 2500.$


Here are the risk curves for quadratic loss:

Lower risk curves are better.  The difficulty is that risk curves usually cross, making it difficult to compare them: for some values of $p$ on estimator will have lower risk while for other values of $p$ the other estimator will have lower risk.  It is (extremely) rare for one procedure to have uniformly lower risk than all others unless you limit the set of procedures you are willing to consider.
Some comments:

The $(1/4, 3/4)$ estimator has constant risk.  Moreover, the largest risk it exhibits is the smallest among these procedures.  It is the minimax estimator: for every other estimator, there will be a range of values of $p$ with worse (larger) risk than this one.  You might choose it when you truly have no idea what $p$ might be and there are some high risks (associated with other procedures) you just cannot tolerate.

The "inverted" estimator is inadmissible in the sense there exists at least one other estimator (such as "Constant") whose risk is never worse, no matter what $p$ might be, and sometimes has a better risk.  You would never want to employ an inadmissible estimator (unless it were quick and easy and not too inadmissible, or if other estimators would be impossible to compute, or if you're not aware your estimator is inadmissible).

For all the other estimators there are values of $p$ for which they have the lowest risk among these estimators. This suggests (correctly) that these other estimators are all admissible.


Here's the same plot of the risks of the same estimators, using the same colors and line types, for the relative loss:

The landscape is profoundly changed compared to quadratic loss.  For instance, whereas for quadratic loss the identity procedure might be a good choice if you felt it likely that $p$ is close to $0,$ that no longer looks so good for relative loss, where now the $(1/4,3/4)$ and Bayes procedure look much better than any of the others we have considered.
Comparing these figures demonstrates the profoundly important role of the loss function in practical statistical problems.
References
Kiefer, Jack C. 2011. Introduction to Statistical Inference. Edited by Gary Lorden. Softcover reprint of the original 1st ed. 1987 edition. New York: Springer.
Code
This R code, which produced the figures, is constructed to handle any loss function and any procedure you care to study.
#
# The parameter space.
# Endpoints are removed to avoid divide-by-zero problems for some loss functions.
#
Omega = tail(head(seq(0, 1, length.out = 501), -1), -1)
# 
# How to compute risk for a single Bernoulli observation: it is expected loss.
#
Risk <- function(t, p, Loss, ...) p * Loss(t[2], p) + (1 - p) * Loss(t[1], p)
#
# How to find the Bayes estimator that minimizes posterior expectation of risk.
#
Bayes <- function(Prior, Loss) {
  f <- Vectorize(function(x) integrate(\(p) p * Loss(x, p) * Prior(p), 0, 1)$value)
  t.1 <- optimize(f, c(0, 1))$minimum
  g <- Vectorize(function(x) integrate(\(p) (1 - p) * Loss(x, p) * Prior(p), 0, 1)$value)
  t.0 <- optimize(g, c(0, 1))$minimum
  c(t.0, t.1)
}
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#
# (That's it for general calculations.  The rest is up to you...)
#
# Specify a list of loss functions to examine. In any loss function,
#   * the first argument is an estimator as the vector (t(0), t(1)).
#   * the second argument is the parameter `p`.
#
losses <- list(Quadratic = function(t, p) (t - p)^2,
                Relative = function(t, p) abs(t - p) / (2 * (t + p)))
#
# Specify a list of estimators to study.
#
Estimators <- list(`(1/4, 3/4)` = c(1/4, 3/4),
                   Constant = c(1/2, 1/2),
                   Identity = c(0, 1),
                   Inverted = c(2/3, 1/3),
                   `Bayes(1,3)` =  Bayes(\(x) dbeta(x, 1, 3), losses$Quadratic))
#
# Plot the risk curves, one plot per loss function.
#
for (loss.type in names(losses)) {
  Loss <- losses[[loss.type]]

  X.lst <- lapply(names(Estimators), \(s) {
    data.frame(Estimator = s, p = Omega, Risk = Risk(Estimators[[s]], Omega, Loss))
  })
  X <- do.call(rbind, args = X.lst)

  require(ggplot2)
  print(ggplot(X, aes(p, Risk)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 3) + 
    geom_path(aes(color = Estimator, linetype = Estimator), size = 1) + 
    ggtitle(paste("Risk Curves for", loss.type, "Loss"), "One Bernoulli Observation") + 
    theme(text = element_text(size = 16)))
}


Thank you for the answer, but I don't see how you use the other know information. We also know the mean. Lets say that the mean $\mu=1200$. How can I estimate $P(x>2500)$?

That's new information, but it's readily accommodated. Specific means will constrain $p.$  In your case, when $p\gt 1200/2500=0.48$ and all values must be non-negative, the mean would have to exceed $1200,$ so $p$ cannot exceed $0.48.$ All smaller values of $p$ are consistent with a mean of $1200.$  So, you would focus your analysis on the values of the risk curves for $p\le 0.48.$  That's really the only modification needed.  In the code, you would limit the parameter space to the interval $[0,0.48]$ by changing ...seq(0, 1, ... to ...seq(0, 0.48, ....

TL:DR. In the first case (unknown distribution), the answer is: we can not estimate $P(x\ge2500)$. In the 2nd case (uniform distribution), it trivially is $\frac {3500} {6000}=.5834$.
Assuming a real-valued random variable X, $P(x\le 2500)=1-F_X(2500)$, where F is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $X$. To solve this we need the CDF, or the probability distribution function (PDF) (the CDF being the integral of the PDF). But we have neither, so we can not answer...
For example, assume X takes the value 0 50% of the time, and 6000 the other 50% of the time. Clearly the answer would be 50%. But now, let's change this to taking the value 0 75% of the time. Now the answer is 25%. Etc... So the answer could be anything...
But if we know the distribution is uniform, then we know its PDF and CDF, and we can answer the question. $P(x\ge2500)=1-F_X(2500)=1-\frac {2500} {6000}=\frac {3500} {6000} =.5834$.

The question doesn't ask to find $F_X:$ it only asks how to estimate $\Pr(X\ge 2500).$  As I remarked in a comment to the question, this is a well-posed problem and has many solutions depending on (among other things) the loss function.  Consequently, your assertion "we can not answer" appears wrong to me.

You say loss function, I say distribution function. We have neither. So, as you said in your comment, and as I showed in my counter examples, there is no unique solution, in fact any numerical value could be true. Also, loss-function, classifier training etc are not beginner topics. But the 2nd question (probability when given uniform distribution) is a simple, almost trivial beginner question. SO I doubt that they belong together.

In implicitly equating loss functions with distribution functions you misunderstand: I recommend consulting any standard textbook on estimation, such as Lehman, Kiefer, or whatever.  One does not need "many such x's": one observation will suffice to make a non-trivial estimate.  This also is explicitly demonstrated in the textbooks.  (-1)

My comment does not mention "many x's":? I did edit it... And I do not equate loss function to distribution function; you misread it. I am just saying that we need 1 or the other, and we have none.

Rather than simply down-voting, it would be very nice if, e.g. @whuber, could enlighten me (and maybe others) by providing their own answers. That would give me a learning moment.

I did not "simply downvote:" I provided an explanation and keywords.  You can use them to find, for instance, our thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208505 which explains many of these concepts and works out a (different) example involving a single observation.
